# Login with salesforce option on an external website redirecting to salesforce home page after login

Tags: apex, single-sign-on

We have a single sign on using webauth as identity provider to login to salesforce. Now, I have an external website where they provide a "Sign in with salesforce" option. Whenever I try to use the "Sign in with salesforce" on the external website, it logs in to the salesforce but does not redirect to the external website. Could someone help with this as to what needs to be done in case so that we are successfully logged into the external website

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a configuration mismatch between Salesforce's Connected App callback URL setting, and the external website's return_uri parameter. Please refer to the [OAuth 2.0 Web Server Flow for Web App Integration](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5) documentation for more information.